# Spring MVC Mysql Spring-Security

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm having a problem trying to figure out what went wrong with my code.
I'm trying to create a user and role management using spring mvc + hibernate + mysql but what happens is all of my page return http 404

my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security --> 
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.model" />


<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.userman.model.Role</value>
            <value>com.spring.userman.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

root-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.userman.model" />


<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/sec/moderation"
        access="ROLE_MODERATOR" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/"
        access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/user-login"
        default-target-url="/success-login" authentication-failure-url="/error-login" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/index" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I suspect the problem come from the security:authencation-manager, because when I replace the authentication provider with a hardcoded user I can access all of my page without the 404 error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Servlet context is the child context of root context. Thus all beans defined in root context are available in servlet context but the one's defined in servlet context are not available in root context.

I am presuming you are doing db interactions in customUserDetailsService thus would have injected/used EM/SessionFactory somehow. However these are defined in servlet context thus these definitions are not available in root context during creations of customUserDetailsService.

The simplest solution may be to move the relevant beans definition (relate to db interactions) to root context. However be careful since you wouldn't have flexibility to do web scoping (request/session etc) of these beans in root context (it's not web aware whereas servlet context in contrast is).